# Как правильно писать константы?

Tags: c#

В C# правильно писать константы вот так:

```
const int MONTHS = 12;
```

или так как пишет здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants ?

```
const int Months = 12;
```

Comment: [Правила именования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines)

Comment: Чтобы отметить вопрос решенным, нужно выбрать наиболее полезный ответ из представленных ниже и поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 0):

Это всего пример, есть документация об "Правильном коде", в  которой вообще ничего не сказано об константах, есть лишь правило об наименовании, пример, первая буква маленькая, а разделение слов в названии идёт без доп символов, каждое слово с большой буквы - itIsCoolVar.
Могу только сказать свою гипотезу: 
Константы пишутся большими буквами ТОЛЬКО когда они находятся в общедоступном статичном классе, обозначающий легкий элемент или целочисленное значение:

```
internal static partial class User32
{
       public static class VK
       {
           public const int TAB = 0x0000;
           public const int SHIFT = 0x0001;
           public const int CONTROL = 0x0002;
           public const int MENU = 0x0003;
       }
}
```

В других же случаях нужно их писать как обычные переменные. 
Как вы понимаете, каждый делает по своему, даже в офф репозитории WinForms есть противоречия:

```
public static class Example
{
   public const int WINDOW = 0x00000000;
   public const int IDC_ARROW = 32512;
   public const int MENU = 0x0003;
   public const string MSFTEDIT_CLASS = "RICHEDIT50W";
   public const string EnableVisualStyles = "ApplicationVisualStyles";
   public const string Comctl32 = "comctl32.dll";
   public const string Code = "Code";
}
```

Comment: Вложенные публичные типы - плохая практика, я бы вообще не рассматривал этот вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Я принимаю константы за обычные поля, и по [CamelCase](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) именую вот так:

```
public const int pi = 3.14;
```

Приватные так же

```
private const int count = 10;
```

Тут главное именовать всё (и переменные и методы) в одном стиле, то есть если ты где то начал, к примеру, именовать так как я написал выше, то старайся придерживаться этого же стиля написания во всем коде.

Answer (score 0):

Я именую приватные поля
`private const int c_name = 12;`

Именую публичные поля
`public const int NameConst = 12;`